# ArcGIS Server performance comparison

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, mapserver, performance, osgeo

Are there any recent comparisons/studies of ArcGIS Server vs. open source GIS servers in common tasks like providing a WMS/WFS, filtering data/search performance, and so on?

We received a lot of critic about featuring this [thesis](http://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/1957/30062/BauerJennifer2012.pdf) on [our blog](http://www.digital-geography.com) as the thesis is outdated and a little bit picky on serving WFS only. Citation from reddit: "This is like comparing two cars based on cup holder design."

There is an older presentation [given here](http://de.slideshare.net/gatewaygeomatics.com/wms-performance-shootout-2010) but like written: It's from 2010